# How do I make a navbar that is centered be responsive friendly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have achieved in making my navbar somewhat centered however it doesn't seem to be very resoponsive friendly. Also, when I collapse the menu my hamburger menu doesn't appear. Any tips would be great!

```css
.navbar-header {
  height: 90px;
 
}

.navbar li {
  
  display: inline;
  padding-top: 20px;
  float: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar {
  background: #003643;
}
 .navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
    color: #ABD7DE !important;
     font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
   text-aline: center;
     
  
}
.navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
    color: #284047 !important;
    background-color: #ABD7DE !important;
  
}

#logo {
  max-height:150px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

#nav .navbar-header{
  max-width: 900px;
  margin-left: 322px;
  margin-right: auto;
}



.jumbotron {
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/500602/mountain.jpeg);
  height: 700px;
  repeat: none;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
}




.button-primary {
  background: #B1DBDF;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div id="nav" class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/500602/Portfolio_pic.jpg" alt="Zachary" /></a>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div style="margin-top:180px" class="row">
      <h1>Welcome to my Portfolio!</h1>
      <h3>I'm so glad you stopped by!</h3>
      <button class="button-primary">Let's get started!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbar-header {
  height: 90px;
 
}

.navbar li {
  
  display: inline;
  padding-top: 20px;
  float: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar {
  background: #003643;
}
 .navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
    color: #ABD7DE !important;
     font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
   text-aline: center;
     
  
}
.navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
    color: #284047 !important;
    background-color: #ABD7DE !important;
  
}

#logo {
  max-height:150px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

#nav .navbar-header{
  max-width: 900px;
  margin-left: 322px;
  margin-right: auto;
}



.jumbotron {
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/500602/mountain.jpeg);
  height: 700px;
  repeat: none;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
}




.button-primary {
  background: #B1DBDF;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}




.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div id="nav" class="container ">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
  </div>
     
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/500602/Portfolio_pic.jpg" alt="Zachary" /></a>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div style="margin-top:180px" class="row">
      <h1>Welcome to my Portfolio!</h1>
      <h3>I'm so glad you stopped by!</h3>
      <button class="button-primary">Let's get started!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```